# HttpFoundation JsonResponse returns Null in PhpUnit test

Tags: json, laravel, testing, phpunit, response

I have a Laravel 8 app that uses Botman. When I call the endpoint from Postman, I get the correct content with the correct headers. But when I call the endpoint while testing I get empty content and thus the test doesn't pass. The response is handled by HttpFoundation JsonResponse. The weird thing is the content is printed in the test console (even when I don't dump) but, $response->dump() returns Null.

**My test method**

```
 /** @test */
public function user_can_talk_to_coach()
{
    Passport::actingAs($this->learner, $this->learnerScopes);

    $response = $this->postJson(
        'learner/v1/coach',
        [
            'driver'  => 'mobile',
            'userId'  => 1,
            'message' => null,
            'intent'  => 'intent_testing',
        ],
        $this->headers
    );

    var_dump('dump');
    $response->dump();
    var_dump('headers');
    $response->dumpHeaders();

    $response->assertStatus(200)
    ->assertJson([
        'data' => [
            [
                'type'                 => 'text',
                'text'                 => 'Hey',
                'attachment'           => null,
                'additionalParameters' => [
                    'node'=> 'testing',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
}
```

**Message sending method**

```
/**
 * Send out message response.
 */
public function messagesHandled()
{
    $messages = $this->buildReply($this->replies);

    // Reset replies
    $this->replies = [];

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData(['data' => $messages]);
    $response->send();
}
```

[Test result capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1LSF.png)

Any idea of what is happening here ?

Comment: What happens when you do `return $response;` instead of `$response->send();`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and actually, with the return, I get absolutely nothing, either in Postman or test... I quite don't understand the working of the send() method and why it is working to be honest...